# Flip key/value pairs from an existing array into an associate array which allows for keys with multiple values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, key-value

I need to basically flip an existing associate array into another associate array. It needs to contain the keys from the previous array as values and the values of the previous array as keys. Also, it needs to be able to contain multiple values for a single key.

**Code:**

```
 class Owner {
 public static function groupOwners($array)
 {
   //insert code
 }
 }
 $array = array(
  "Input.txt" => "Bob",
  "Code.py" => "Steve",
  "Output.txt" => "Bob"
 );
 var_dump(Owner::groupOwners($array));
```

The output generated is to be:

```
["Bob"] => ["Input.txt, Output.txt"], ["Steve"] => ["Code.py"]
```

Comment: And where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show an attempt but I'm bored:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $result[$val][] = $key;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. Haven't had to deal with arrays in PHP until recently and have been trying to find an answer for a while.